# Need Help Moving Titles and Adding Prev/Next Buttons to Pure CSS/HTML Slider

Tags: html, css, button, slider

Due to my lack of experience with more advanced CSS/HTML, I picked up a pure CSS/HTML slider from Codepen.io and laboriously experimented so it looks (mostly) as I desire. I want to keep using it, if possible. The two changes I've been unable to make are:

1. Get the synchronized image titles to appear centered below the slider instead of centered above it.
2. Add previous and next buttons OUTSIDE the left and right sides of the slider. Note: if you click a thumbnail below the slider, you can then use the keyboard arrow keys to do a previous and next, so the functionality is already there.

My CSS/HTML code is here:
https://codepen.io/Photog/pen/MWmreya
Note: I know the slider looks way too large in Codepen with the thumbnails I've included. It looks fine with my actual images.
I've added comments to indicate what I've tried and didn't work.

```css
/* : is for a pseudo-class. :root matches the HTML element */


/* Define variables for colors */

:root {
  --bgnormal: black;
  --fgnormal: white;
  --bordercolor: gray;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* ========================================= * 
    Modification of 
   https://codepen.io/ig_design/full/NWxwBvw
   https://codepen.io/ig_design/pen/NWxwBvw
 * ========================================= */

body {
  font-weight: 300;
  /* between normal and bold=700 */
  background-color: var(--bgnormal);
  overflow-x: hidden;
}


/* , separates a list of selectors being styled the same way */

body,
caption,
div,
dd,
dl,
dt,
form,
li,
option,
p,
select,
td,
th,
tr,
u {
  font-family: Helvetica, Verdana, "Lucida Sans", Tahoma, Arial, "Century Gothic", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 140%;
  color: var(--fgnormal);
}


/* . (leading) means this is a class */

.section {
  position: relative;
  /* can be positioned relative to its normal position via top, right, bottom, left */
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-alignment: center;
}

.slider-height-padding {
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Do not reduce this. Current pix are 80px high */
}


/* all radio buttons (thumbnails), checked or not */


/* , separates a list of selectors being styled the same way */


/* : is for a pseudo-class. They show state (e.g., hover, visited, checked) */

[type="radio"]:checked,
[type="radio"]:not(:checked) {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  /* a negative left with position: absolute means set the left edge to a unit to the left of he left edge of its nearest positioned ancestor */
}


/* thumbnail buttons */


/* + ("adjacent sibling combinator") means first you see selector 1 (and its closing) and directly afterward you style selector 2 */

.checkbox:checked+label,
.checkbox:not(:checked)+label {
  position: relative;
  /* can be positioned relative to its normal position via top, right, bottom, left */
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 6px;
  margin-left: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid var(--bordercolor);
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  opacity: 50%;
  /* Not so bright */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-image: url('https://fullbrain.com/images/AAInchBW.jpg');
}

.checkbox.c02+label {
  background-image: url('https://fullbrain.com/images/AAInchRestful.jpg');
}

.checkbox.c03+label {
  background-image: url('https://fullbrain.com/images/AAInchLively.jpg');
}

.checkbox:checked+label {
  opacity: 1;
  /* Make the checked button have full intensity/opacity */
}

ul {
  position: absolute;
  /* can be positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor via top, right, bottom, left */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}


/* title and box, not thumbnails */


/* space ("descendent selector") means styled selector 2 is enclosed in selector 1 */

ul li {
  position: absolute;
  /* can be positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor via top, right, bottom, left */
  top: 0;
  /* when I tried bottom: 0, the box disappeared */
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* auto wasn't good */
  height: 120px;
  /* IMPORTANT was 400px. At 500px, I see titles above slider. At 800px, slider moves down and covers thumbnails, but title stays. */
  display: block;
  z-index: 100;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-size: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url('https://fullbrain.com/images/AAInchBW.jpg');
  border: 5px solid var(--bgnormal);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  /* This is for the image title */
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: var(--fgnormal);
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}


/* I think this is the label */


/* space ("descendent selector") means styled selector 3 is enclosed in selector 2 is enclosed in selector 1 */

ul li span {
  mix-blend-mode: normal;
  /* was difference */
  /* vertical-align: bottom;  no-op */
  /* position: relative; bottom: 0; is a no-op */
}


/* space ("descendent selector") means styled selector 2 is enclosed in selector 1 */


/* : is for pseudo-classes. They show state (e.g., hover, visited, checked), nth-child is ordinal */

ul li:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url('https://fullbrain.com/images/AAInchRestful.jpg');
}

ul li:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: url('https://fullbrain.com/images/AAInchLively.jpg');
}


/* . (leading) means this is a class */


/* . (internal) means is a member of both classes */


/* : is for pseudo-classes. They show state (e.g., hover, visited, checked), nth-child is ordinal */


/* ~ ("subsequent sibling combinator" or "general sibling selector") means first you see selector 1 and then style all selector 2s that follow */


/* space ("descendent selector") means styled selector 2 is enclosed in selector 1 */

.checkbox.c01:checked~ul li:nth-child(1) {
  opacity: 1;
  /* full intensity/opacity */
  pointer-events: auto;
  border-radius: 16px;
}

.checkbox.c02:checked~ul li:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 1;
  /* full intensity/opacity */
  pointer-events: auto;
  border-radius: 16px;
}

.checkbox.c03:checked~ul li:nth-child(3) {
  opacity: 1;
  /* full intensity/opacity */
  pointer-events: auto;
  border-radius: 16px;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="section slider-height-padding">
  <br>
  <!-- I have no idea why this text appears BELOW the slider -->
  <center>Click a thumbnail below to see the larger image and title.</center>

  <input class="checkbox c01" type="radio" name="slider" id="slide-1" checked>
  <label for="slide-1"></label>

  <input class="checkbox c02" type="radio" name="slider" id="slide-2">
  <label for="slide-2"></label>

  <input class="checkbox c03" type="radio" name="slider" id="slide-3">
  <label for="slide-3"></label>

  <ul>
    <li><span style="color: white;">Spray-On Beauty</span></li>
    <li><span style="color: white;">Dante's Inferno</span></li>
    <li><span style="color: yellow;">Boots Made for Walking</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the position of your label span like this.

```css
li span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -13px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}


/* : is for a pseudo-class. :root matches the HTML element */


/* Define variables for colors */

:root {
  --bgnormal: black;
  --fgnormal: white;
  --bordercolor: gray;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* ========================================= * 
    Modification of 
   https://codepen.io/ig_design/full/NWxwBvw
   https://codepen.io/ig_design/pen/NWxwBvw
 * ========================================= */

body {
  font-weight: 300;
  /* between normal and bold=700 */
  background-color: var(--bgnormal);
  overflow-x: hidden;
}


/* , separates a list of selectors being styled the same way */

body,
caption,
div,
dd,
dl,
dt,
form,
li,
option,
p,
select,
td,
th,
tr,
u {
  font-family: Helvetica, Verdana, "Lucida Sans", Tahoma, Arial, "Century Gothic", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 140%;
  color: var(--fgnormal);
}


/* . (leading) means this is a class */

.section {
  position: relative;
  /* can be positioned relative to its normal position via top, right, bottom, left */
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-alignment: center;
}

.slider-height-padding {
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Do not reduce this. Current pix are 80px high */
}


/* all radio buttons (thumbnails), checked or not */


/* , separates a list of selectors being styled the same way */


/* : is for a pseudo-class. They show state (e.g., hover, visited, checked) */

[type="radio"]:checked,
[type="radio"]:not(:checked) {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  /* a negative left with position: absolute means set the left edge to a unit to the left of he left edge of its nearest positioned ancestor */
}


/* thumbnail buttons */


/* + ("adjacent sibling combinator") means first you see selector 1 (and its closing) and directly afterward you style selector 2 */

.checkbox:checked+label,
.checkbox:not(:checked)+label {
  position: relative;
  /* can be positioned relative to its normal position via top, right, bottom, left */
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 6px;
  margin-left: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid var(--bordercolor);
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  opacity: 50%;
  /* Not so bright */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-image: url('https://fullbrain.com/images/AAInchBW.jpg');
}

.checkbox.c02+label {
  background-image: url('https://fullbrain.com/images/AAInchRestful.jpg');
}

.checkbox.c03+label {
  background-image: url('https://fullbrain.com/images/AAInchLively.jpg');
}

.checkbox:checked+label {
  opacity: 1;
  /* Make the checked button have full intensity/opacity */
}

ul {
  position: absolute;
  /* can be positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor via top, right, bottom, left */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}


/* title and box, not thumbnails */


/* space ("descendent selector") means styled selector 2 is enclosed in selector 1 */

ul li {
  position: absolute;
  /* can be positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor via top, right, bottom, left */
  top: 0;
  /* when I tried bottom: 0, the box disappeared */
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* auto wasn't good */
  height: 120px;
  /* IMPORTANT was 400px. At 500px, I see titles above slider. At 800px, slider moves down and covers thumbnails, but title stays. */
  display: block;
  z-index: 100;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-size: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url('https://fullbrain.com/images/AAInchBW.jpg');
  border: 5px solid var(--bgnormal);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  /* This is for the image title */
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: var(--fgnormal);
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}


/* I think this is the label */


/* space ("descendent selector") means styled selector 3 is enclosed in selector 2 is enclosed in selector 1 */

ul li span {
  mix-blend-mode: normal;
  /* was difference */
  /* vertical-align: bottom;  no-op */
  /* position: relative; bottom: 0; is a no-op */
}


/* space ("descendent selector") means styled selector 2 is enclosed in selector 1 */


/* : is for pseudo-classes. They show state (e.g., hover, visited, checked), nth-child is ordinal */

ul li:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url('https://fullbrain.com/images/AAInchRestful.jpg');
}

ul li:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: url('https://fullbrain.com/images/AAInchLively.jpg');
}


/* . (leading) means this is a class */


/* . (internal) means is a member of both classes */


/* : is for pseudo-classes. They show state (e.g., hover, visited, checked), nth-child is ordinal */


/* ~ ("subsequent sibling combinator" or "general sibling selector") means first you see selector 1 and then style all selector 2s that follow */


/* space ("descendent selector") means styled selector 2 is enclosed in selector 1 */

.checkbox.c01:checked~ul li:nth-child(1) {
  opacity: 1;
  /* full intensity/opacity */
  pointer-events: auto;
  border-radius: 16px;
}

.checkbox.c02:checked~ul li:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 1;
  /* full intensity/opacity */
  pointer-events: auto;
  border-radius: 16px;
}

.checkbox.c03:checked~ul li:nth-child(3) {
  opacity: 1;
  /* full intensity/opacity */
  pointer-events: auto;
  border-radius: 16px;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="section slider-height-padding">
  <br>
  <!-- I have no idea why this text appears BELOW the slider -->
  <center>Click a thumbnail below to see the larger image and title.</center>

  <input class="checkbox c01" type="radio" name="slider" id="slide-1" checked>
  <label for="slide-1"></label>

  <input class="checkbox c02" type="radio" name="slider" id="slide-2">
  <label for="slide-2"></label>

  <input class="checkbox c03" type="radio" name="slider" id="slide-3">
  <label for="slide-3"></label>

  <ul>
    <li><span style="color: white;">Spray-On Beauty</span></li>
    <li><span style="color: white;">Dante's Inferno</span></li>
    <li><span style="color: yellow;">Boots Made for Walking</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @Photog, you're welcome, but please take the [tour]. "Thanks" comments are discouraged. Use votes and acceptance instead.